# How to use data models in flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, model, bloc

I have one screen for input phone number and use bloc,
for emit event in bloc class and fetch request from api if it valid navigate to new page

but i can't understand where store my data model? (in event classes or in state classes or even in bloc class)

Comment: What do you mean by store? Do you mean passing it to your main widget?

Answer (score 1):

Your data model will just be a regular Dart class.

In your bloc class there will be instances of your data models.
When your bloc class receives an Event, it will call functions in your data model and send out a State.